# What are all the locations of the Black Books?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I seem to be missing one black book. So what are all the locations of the black books? How many are there in total?

Comment: there's no requirement to add a comment for a DV

Comment: I guess I deserve a whooosh :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are seven Black Books in total. The [wiki page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Books) gives these locations:

*Epistolary Acumen* - Found in Nchardak during the quest "The Path of Knowledge".

*Filament and Filigree* - Found in Kolbjorn Barrow during the quest "Unearthed".

*The Hidden Twilight* - Found in Tel Mithryn, next to the Staff Enchanter.

*The Sallow Regent* - Found in White Ridge Sanctum, you will have to go through the White Ridge Barrow first.

*The Winds of Change* - Found in Bloodskal Barrow, during the quest "The Final Descent".

*Untold Legends* - Found in Benkongerike, after the word wall.

*Waking Dreams* - Found in the Temple of Miraak during the main questline.

You can also get the Black Book locations from Neloth in the quest [Lost Knowledge](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Knowledge) - this is repeatable in the same way you can ask the Grey Beards for word wall locations. Doing it this way nets a handy 1000 Septims for each completion.